# How to build a query string with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that builds a query string:

```
    var name = $(this).next()[0].name;
    var value = $(this).next()[0].checked;
    var str = name+'&value='+value;
```

and outputs an array on my server like this:

```
[value] => false
```

---

What I would like to have is something more like this:

```
array(
    [myInputName] => value
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Change `'&value'` to `'&myInputName'`

Comment: The problem is that the function handles all of the checkboxes. They are dynamic in  nature. I need to be able to tell which one was clicked/checked

Comment: You  mean like `var str = name + '=' + value`?

Comment: Uh, yessir. :)  Please post it and I'll credit you for the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
var str = name + '=' + value;
```

What you have would output something like:

```
myInputName&value=myInputValue
```

Using `name` in that way is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, take a look at [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to build query strings. For example:

```
var p = {};
p[name] = value;
var str = $.param(p)
```

Although it's overkill for your simple example, it'll help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try `$('yourselection').serialize()`
This will produce a querystring for you from the inputs those have names. 
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

And check param too. It works nice for custom parameters.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/